# Comparison function for C++ STL set: Can comparison function be a member function of a class?

Tags: c++, stl, set

I have to use STL set and I want to define my own comparison function. But as per my requirement this comparison function shouldn't be a global, rather should be a public member of a class.

```
//CLASS DEFINITION
class IDENTIFERS
{
public:
         IDENTIFIERS();
         ~IDENTIFIERS();
bool     compare_identifier(int Identifier, int Identifier);

public:
std::set <Identifier, bool(*)(Identifier, Identifier)>      set_instance;

};

//CLASS Constructor
IDENTIFIERS::IDENTIFIERS()
{
std::set <Identifier, bool(*)(Identifier, Identifier)>   set_instance(compare_identifier);
}
```

If I write a piece a code as mentioned above. It doesn't compile as comparison function's prototype doesn't match with compare_identifier() function.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Make your member function `static`.

Comment: A note on coding style: Most people I know would assume an all-uppercase identifier to be either an enumerator or a macro.

Comment: Note that the set you declare in the constructor is not the same set you have as a data member. Your constructor isn't doing anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-static member function takes an implicit first parameter for `this`, so your `compare_identifier` actually has three parameters. If you need it to be a non-static member function, you need to bind the member function's implicit first parameter to an instance of `IDENTIFIERS`, for example,

```
#include <set>
#include <functional>

struct Identifier { int id; };

class IDENTIFERS
{
public:
  IDENTIFERS() : set_instance(std::bind(&IDENTIFERS::compare_identifier,
                                        this,                                               
                                        std::placeholders::_1,
                                        std::placeholders::_2))
  {}
  bool  compare_identifier(const Identifier& lhs, const Identifier& rhs)
  {
    return lhs.id < rhs.id;
  }

public:
  std::set <Identifier, std::function<bool(const Identifier&, const Identifier&)>> set_instance;

};
```

Comment: If instead of "int Identifier", I want to compare some other type (say void*). The above mentioned statement still holds true? Also, I am getting one error "bind is not a member of std" even after including <functional>. Any specific reason?

Comment: @harshmeet yes, it would work in the same way. You need C++11 support to get `std::bind`.

Comment: Yes, I did that. Now I'm getting following compilation errors:  error: no matching function for call to âstd::set<id_type*, bool (IDENTIFIER::*)(id_type*, id_type*), std::allocator<id_type*> >::set(std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<bool (IDENTIFIER::*)(id_type*, id_type*)>(IDENTIFIER*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>)>)â         Note: Here id_type is nothing but type of argument to comparison funcion. I think, still I'm missing something in my code.

Comment: @harshmeet I extended my example. I haven't fully tested it but it compiles. There were a few other errors in your code, which I attempted to fix/remove.

Answer (score 0):

Making `compare_identifier()` `static` is the easiest way to solve this. Here is how you can fix your code so that it compiles, assuming `Identifier` is defined elsewhere:

```
// Watch for the typo (missing 'I') in your code above
class IDENTIFIERS // Note, all-uppercase names are usually reserved for macros
{
public:
    IDENTIFIERS();

    // N.B: This function needs to take two `Identifier`s as its arguments
    // (not two `int`s)    
    static bool compare_identifier(Identifier const &l, Identifier const& r)
    {
       return l.custom_less_than(r);
    }

    // typedefs can make your code more readable, especially with function pointers.
    typedef bool (*identifier_comparator)(Identifier const &l, Identifier const& r);
    typedef std::set<Identifier, identifier_comparator> identifier_set;
    identifier_set set_instance;
};

IDENTIFIERS::IDENTIFIERS()
    :set_instance(compare_identifier) // Initialise here
{
    // Don't shadow `set_instance` in the body of the constructor!
}
```

### Following comment

Making `compare_identifier()` `static` (in `IDENTIFIERS`) will *not* affect the accessibility of members of the `Identifier` `class`. The logic to compare two `Identifier` objects should reside either within `Identifier`, like this:

```
class Identifier
{
public:
    // If you define this, then you won't need to specify a custom comparator
    bool operator <(Identifier const& r) const
    {
        // return true if `*this` is logically less-than `r`; false otherwise.
    }

    bool custom_less_than(Identifier const& r) const
    {
        // Some other way of comparing objects. Perhaps reverse-alphabetically
        // or similar.
        // return true if `*this` is logically less-than `r`; false otherwise.
    } 
};
```

...or within *free functions* but these won't have access to the `private` members.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I can not use static as I want to access some private members of the class in the comparison function. I have to do some computation using private data members of the class and then perform comparison. I don't think that even functor would help here. Please suggest.

Comment: @harshmeet You are mistaken. A member being static doesn't prevent it from accessing private members of instances of the class it is defined in.

Comment: @harshmeet: I've updated my answer in an effort to clarify. It would help us if you were less vague about the design of the `Identifier` class and what it is you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of errors in your sample code.

The zero-th error is somewhat style-related: classes should be named all-lowercase-with-underscores or CamelCase.

The first error:

```
bool compare_identifier(int Identifier, int Identifier);
```

you can't have the same identifier for both function parameters (also, style-related, function parameters should be all-lowercase or camelCased), like

```
bool compare_identifier(int id1, int id2);
```

The second error is that this:

```
std::set <Identifier, bool(*)(Identifier, Identifier)> set_instance;
```

assumes that you have a `class Identifier` somewhere. Which something tells me you don't, since your class is called `IDENTIFIERS`. If you **do** have an `Identifier` class, I should assume that your `compare_identifier` function is like:

```
bool compare_identifier(const Identifier& id1, const Identifier& id2);
```

and that your `set_instance` declaration is like:

```
std::set<Identifier, bool(*)(const Identifier&, const Identifier&)> set_instance;
```

The third error is that your constructor does not do what you are assuming it does (constructing the `set_instance` member), but it would be (if syntatically valid) constructing a **local variable** called `set_instance`. So, your constructor should go something like:

```
IdentifierBucket::IdentifierBucket() :
  set_instance(std::bind(compare_identifier, this, _1, _2)) {
}
```

But all this is moot... because the comparator for `set` also does not do what you think it does (see if two items are equal or not) but it gives them **order** (the default comparator is `std::less`...

What you **really** want is something like:

```
#include <set>
#include <functional>

struct Identifier {};

struct IdentifierComparator {
  IdentifierComparator() {};
  bool operator()(Identifier id1, Identifier id2); // WRITE THIS
};

class IdentifierBucket {
public:
  IdentifierBucket() {};
  ~IdentifierBucket() {};

private:
  std::set <Identifier, IdentifierComparator> set_instance;
};
```